# Como ordenar uma lista pela quantidade de ocorrências? Em Python

Tags: python, classificação, lista

Tipo, eu tenho uma lista assim:

```
lista = [1,1,2,3,3,3]
```

E quero ordená-la pra ficar

```
lista = [3,3,3,1,1,2]
```

Ou seja, os valores mais ocorrentes ficariam no começo da lista, enquanto os valores menos ocorrentes no final. Já tentei várias funções, mas não deu certo.

Comment: A lista é assim: lista = [1,1,2,3,3,3] e quero que seja ordenada por quantidade de ocorrência, então ela ficaria: lista = [3,3,3,1,1,2]. Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
from collections import Counter

lista = [1,1,2,3,3,3]

print [item for items, c in Counter(lista).most_common() for item in [items] * c]

# [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Poderia explicar sua resposta ?

Comment: Este "for items, c in Counter(lista).most_common()" retorna os valores da sua lista e a quantidade de vezes que ele se repete, o restante trata de preencher esta lista com item * c ou seja valor x a quantidade de vezes que o valor se repete em sua lista.
Vai desculpando a explicação apressada, mas estou saindo aqui.
Se não resolver desta forma avise o erro que poderei te ajudar assim que retornar.

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/266231/edit) sua resposta e coloque nela sua explicação. Você não testou esse código para dizer "**Se não resolver...**" ?

Comment: Deu super certo Raphael! Muito obrigado amigo, serviu demais! Ainda não conhecia essa biblioteca Counter. Agradecido pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Caso não queira usar bibliotecas, aqui vai uma ideia usando dicionários:

Primeiro crio um dicionário com as ocorrências

```
lista = [1,1,2,3,3,3]
ocorrencias = {}

for numero in lista:
    if numero in ocorrencias: #Se o numero ja esta no dicionario
        ocorrencias[numero] += 1
    else: #Se não está, adiciono em ocorrencias
        ocorrencias[numero] = 1
        #OU ocorrencias.update({numero:1})

>>> print ocorrencias
{1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3}
```

Depois crio a lista ordenada a partir do dicionário de ocorrências

```
def pega_maior_ocorrencia(dicionario):
    maior_ocorrencia = 0
    chave = None
    for key, value in dicionario.iteritems(): #Python2.X
    #for key, value in d.items(): #Python3.X
        if value > maior_ocorrencia:
            maior_ocorrencia = value
            chave = key
    del dicionario[chave] #deleta do dict mesmo dentro da função
    return [chave]*maior_ocorrencia

lista_ocorrencias = []

for i in range(len(ocorrencias)):
    lista_ocorrencias += pega_maior_ocorrencia(ocorrencias)

>>> print lista_ocorrencias
[3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2]
```